# How can I reclaim "nth" for bash in eshell?

Tags: eshell

In bash I commonly use an alias 'nth' (hint: it makes sense as a key-combo if you use Dvorak layout). When I type this in eshell, I see:

```
~ $ nth
usage: nth: (N LIST)
```

How can I get eshell ignore `nth` as a lisp command?

Comment: I suggest rephrasing your question. There's no such thing as "reclaiming" anything for bash from eshell, since bash is nowhere in the picture (in particular, eshell is *not* sitting on top of bash). Therefore, removing the `nth` definition from eshell would not make the bash definition pop magically. So I guess your question is more about (automatically?) import bash aliases definition in eshell.

Comment: Ah yes! I thought eshell was an interface to the bash shell. I realize now it is an entirely new shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to redefine the alias for eshell.

For instance if you alias `nth` to `echo hi` in bash then in eshell type `alias nth echo hi`

eshell will write your aliases to your `eshell-alias-file` where they will persist.